# Is it possible to fill in multiple inputs in parallel with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I want to type into 2 inputs at the same time but in fact both texts go to the second input.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://example.com");

  await Promise.all([
    page.type("#user", "user"),
    page.type("#password", "password"),
  ]);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

The second input looks like `upsaesrsword`

Comment: That would be because you can't type in two places at once. You can only have focus on one input at a time. Remember: you're writing user interaction here, users can't type in two places at once on a webpage.

Comment: [Why do you want to do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876)? If typing is too slow for some reason (hard to believe), some sites might let you do `page.$eval("#user", el => el.value = "user")`.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is intended.
Related issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1958

Alternative solution:

```
page.$eval(
    '#user', 
    (handle, text) => {
        handle.value = text;
        handle.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles}));
    },
    'user'
);
```